# How to center text within label in a map chart in spotfire?

Tags: spotfire

How to center the text within a label in a map chart in Spotfire? I tried the labels option but it doesn't have an option to align the text.

Answer (score 0):

sadly, there is no feature to align text inside of a label, and the label formatting features are a bit limited. this goes for all of the other chart types that support labels, too.

one really silly idea I just thought of and haven't tried would be to change the label to use a monospace font like Courier New, and then calculate how many spaces you'd need to place on the left to make the text appear centered, but herein lies only madness and I wouldn't seriously recommend this approach to anyone.